# Как увеличить количество строк в файле xls, создаваемом библиотекой Spreadsheet на PHP

Tags: php, xls, xlsx

При создании и загрузке файла xls библиотекой Spreadsheet на PHP, полученный файл имеет ограничение по количеству строк в 65536. Как увеличить это значение для записи на один лист? Пробовал изменить это значение в свойстве класса самой библиотеке - не принесло успеха. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это ограничение формата xls. Попробуйте xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил таким образом: 1 - создал файл в формате xlsx (как порекомендовали выше), 2 - использовал библиотеку PHPExcel, которая позволяет записывать в файл в данном формате.